# infinite dimensional quotient of a $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

If $A$ is a  noncommutative  non unital $C^*$ algebra,does there exist a nontrivial ideal $J$ of $A$ such that the dimension of $A/J$ is infinite?

Comment: No, $A$ could be finite-dimensional, for example.

Comment: I mean $A$ is infinite dimensional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Take any simple non-unital infinite dimensional $C^*$-algebra.